# Format or Style string in email

Tags: css, email, plsql

I have a string returned from a function to be sent as an Plain Text email  in the body part automatically. How could I make some words to display **bold** style or change the size of the word in the email ?

Comment: What kind of an E-Mail is it - plain text or HTML?

Comment: No way then. You'll need to use HTML E-Mails to apply any kind of formatting.

Comment: @Pekka eh... disappointed . Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the email is plain text, there is no way to make any visible styles on the text.